# How to return and access two query result in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

I have two different query results (not related to each other).

I am returning them by one DataSet in SSRS 2016.

Now I want to display that data in one single report.

How do I access two different query result sets in SSRS 2016?

Please let me know if it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can return one `SELECT` statement per dataset. If the columns are the same you can `UNION` the results into one. Otherwise, use two separate datasets. If you end up using two datasets and need to compare the results use the `Lookup` function.

Answer (score 1):

You should set up two data sets in your report to get the two different query results.